# Issue with repeated letters while creating random letter mapping in H2 SQL

Tags: sql, h2

I'm attempting to create a table that randomly maps letters on a 1:1 basis to another letter, I'm fairly certain the script i have should do it but it seems to end up repeating letters  in my random table, example A -> P and F -> P, but only one letter should map to P.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS chrs;

CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE chrs as (
SELECT CHAR(X) as chr from SYSTEM_RANGE(48,90)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS letters_upper;
CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE letters_upper as(
SELECT
        row_number() OVER () as row_number,
        chr
FROM
        chrs
WHERE
    chr ~ '[A-Z]');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS letters_random;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS letters_random;

CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE     letters_random as (
SELECT
    letters_upper.chr,
    lrs.chr AS chr_random
FROM
    letters_upper,
    (
        SELECT
            row_number() OVER () as row_number,
            chr
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    chr
                FROM
                    letters_upper
                ORDER BY random()
            ) qu
    ) lrs
WHERE
    letters_upper.row_number = lrs.row_number);

select chr_random, count(chr_random) from letters_random group by chr_random having count(chr_random) > 1
```

The sub query 'lrs' when i run it in alone seems to do as I intend, and create a random ordered set of letters each unique, and number them 1 - 26. But when combine with the outside query i am getting letters repeating, Can anyone see what's wrong with this or know or a better way to create my letters_random table?

Comment: What I am wondering here is, is the sub query begin re run for each join, and changing the order of the table each time?